# need help appending a two dimensional array

Tags: arrays, swift, struct, append, 2d

why does the second line not work ?

twoDWeeksArray.append(ExpandableWeeks(isExpanded: true, dates: ([weeksArray[0]])))

twoDWeeksArray[0].append(ExpandableWeeks(isExpanded: true, dates: ([weeksArray[x]])))

it gives me this error :

Value of type 'ExpandableWeeks' has no member 'append'

im trying to append a 2d array of dates grouped by year

```
struct ExpandableWeeks { 
    var isExpanded: Bool = true 
    var dates: [Date] 
}
```

here is my func :

```
func getTwoDWeeksArray() {

        twoDWeeksArray.removeAll()
        let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
        dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy"

        var firstYear = dateFormatter.string(from: dailyEntry[0].date!)
        var tempEntry = ""
        var z = 0

        twoDWeeksArray.append(ExpandableWeeks(dates: ([weeksArray[0]])))
        if weeksArray.count == 1 {
             return
        }

        for x in 1...weeksArray.count-1 {
            tempEntry = dateFormatter.string(from: weeksArray[x])
            if tempEntry == firstYear {
                twoDWeeksArray[z].append(ExpandableWeeks( dates: ([weeksArray[x]])))
            } else {
                firstYear = tempEntry
                twoDWeeksArray.append(ExpandableWeeks(isExpanded: true, dates: ([weeksArray[x]])))
                z = z + 1
            }
       }
}
```

Comment: Are you trying to append to the `.dates`?

Comment: Show your code declaration for twoDWeeksArray.

Comment: im trying to append a 2d array --  twoDWeeksArray of type dates that are fed from the weeks array.  it was working until I applied the struct ExpandableWeeks to it

Comment: Please show your code for `struct ExpandableWeeks` and declaration for `var twoDWeeksArray`

Comment: struct ExpandableWeeks {
   
    var isExpanded: Bool = true
    var dates: [Date]
    
}

Comment: before I added the struct the code was working adding an array of dates to the 2d array sectioned by years  I watched a YouTube video to learn how to make my tableview collapsible by the headers for each year  after applying the struct this section gives me errors

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have not shown your declaration for twoDWeeksArray so I can only assume it isn't declared as a 2-dimensional array.

Here is a working example using your struct, although I think perhaps the way your types are being defined is needlessly complex:

```
struct ExpandableWeeks {
    var isExpanded: Bool = true
    var dates: [Date]
}

var myDates = [Date(), Date()]

var twoDWeeksArray: [[ExpandableWeeks]] = [] // 2D Array declaration

// Append works here because it is declared as a 2D array
twoDWeeksArray.append( [ExpandableWeeks(isExpanded: true, dates: myDates )] )    
twoDWeeksArray[0].append( ExpandableWeeks(isExpanded: true, dates: myDates ))

print(twoDWeeksArray.count)
print(twoDWeeksArray[0].count)

// accessing the 2D Array's elements
print(twoDWeeksArray[0][0])
print(twoDWeeksArray[0][1])
```

Log output:

```
1
2
ExpandableWeeks(isExpanded: true, dates: [2020-03-11 01:05:06 +0000, 2020-03-11 01:05:06 +0000])
ExpandableWeeks(isExpanded: true, dates: [2020-03-11 01:05:06 +0000, 2020-03-11 01:05:06 +0000])
```

Comment: var twoDWeeksArray = [ExpandableWeeks(isExpanded: true, dates: [Date]())]

Comment: let me try declaring it your way

Comment: Notice in my example I declared `twoDWeeksArray` with double square brackets. Basically the number of square brackets determines the number of dimensions in your array.  Your declaration means that your `twoDWeeksArray` is just a 1D array of type `ExpandableWeeks`.

Comment: var twoDWeeksArray = [[Date]]().   this is how I declared it before I added the struct  then I had to change it to handle the struct someone suggested the new one and it worked. I do have the extra brackets in there though don't I ?  in front and at the end

Comment: Indeed, your original declaration is a 2D Array.  Your question specifically asks why the append line `twoDWeeksArray[0].append(ExpandableWeeks(isExpanded: true, dates: ([weeksArray[x]])))` does not work.  And there you have your answer.  When you changed the declaration from a 2D array to a 1D array, that line of code stopped working.  You'll have to decide on the implementation you want to use, and work from there.

Comment: ok. that works!  but now I have errors all over where I added .date to my twoDWeeksArray in didSelectRowAt and CellForRowAt     thanks for your help though. its greatly appreciated.   in case you were wondering im trying to use this to handle expand and close rows in a tableview from its headers.

Comment: Sure, I'm happy to help!  My one piece of advice is to clarify that your types are declared as simply as possible, and suited specifically to the task they were designed for.  Good luck with making your tableview work :)

Comment: ill try. im really new to this, this is my first app and I think im in way over my head now.   do you do any freelance work? I might need to hire you. lol.

Comment: Sure you wouldn't prefer to hire someone locally? It's pretty hard to exchange contact info as well on SO since it does not support private messages.  You can leave your email or some other contact info though, if you don't mind it being public..  I'll try and get back to you as soon as I can

Comment: donny@timberlox.com